# problem with 512x512 app icon in iTunes Connect

Tags: icons, app-store, app-store-connect, artwork

I'm uploading my app to App Store and I created it in iTunes Connect.
I just uploaded my 512x512px icon and then I opened Version Summary page to verify my information...
I've got a set of icon that just have gloss effect. In Version Summary page I see my 512x512px icon with automatic gloss added.

Is there a way to prevent this? My large app icon mustn't have gloss...
In my info.plist I added the line "Icon already includes gloss effects" and I checked the box near it...

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Apple Dev Document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW2) includes all of the information you should need for you icon.

The plist entry you are looking for to disable the added gloss is UIPrerenderedIcon. That should prevent Apple from adding gloss. However it will apply to all of you icons.

Comment: I think Matthew is talking specifically about the icons sent up to iTunes Connect which picks up a gloss after you upload the 512x512 image.  Does Apple later look at the UIPrerenderedIcon in your app for what it presents in the store?

Comment: @tofutim I would agree that's what Matthew is talking about, but unfortunately I don't have any experience publishing to the App Store. So I can't comment on your question. (Maybe Matthew can share his experiences)

Answer (score 16):

According to [512x512 image for AppStore (iTunes Connect), will Apple do corner rounding like they do on the phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580978/512x512-image-for-appstore-itunes-connect-will-apple-do-corner-rounding-like-t), Apple does in fact check the app for the UIPrerenderedIcon flag.  Once the app is uploaded, the 512x512 large icon will pick up the correct setting.