# How to upload App Store icon for high-resolution screens?

Tags: app-store-connect

The new [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) states that we should upload an 1024x1024 app icon for high-resolution iPhone and iPad. I've added a new version of my app some days ago, and now when I press "edit" in *Version information* I only have the option to upload an 512x512 App Store icon. Are you able to upload the 1024x1024 app icon?

Comment: I think that "coming soon" is the current state. :)

Comment: It is not possible to change the App Store icon after upload, right? Then we have to wait uploading our new iOS 5.1 App until this is available.

Comment: If the app is already live - you cannot change the icon. If the app is in a state such as Waiting for Review, then you can change the large icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple has changed the description for the icon within iTunes Connect. When you supply an upgrade you're now able to replace your 512x512 icon with an 1024x1024 icon.

1. Click "Edit" next to "Version Information" of your new version
2. Scroll down to the icon and press "Choose File"
3. Select the 1024x1024 icon on your harddrive

The icon will look strange directly after the upload (at least it did in my case). But don't worry, just wait a few minutes and the glossy effect will be applied. I guess Apple's running a script to convert the image (or somehow create a preview of the image) only every 3 minutes or something like that.

Comment: I don't want a darn glossy effect. How to eliminate????? Note: this is for the iTunes Connect icon uploaded when preparing an update to an existing app.

Comment: I think Apple (unfortunately in your case) does that automatically. See the anwer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580978/512x512-image-for-appstore-itunes-connect-will-apple-do-corner-rounding-like

Answer (score 1):

Anything new on this topic? Anytime I try to upload a retina-icon, iTunes connect tells me "Large icons must be 512 x 512 pixels."

This seems a bit odd to me, since Apple clearly states, as Dennis mentioned, that it should be 1024 x 1024 for high-res devices.

Comment: Which device will display the 1024 high-res icon? At the moment there isn't any. Will there be a Retina Macbook? :D